# Windows: .py files not associated with Python after installation

Tags: python, installation, file-association

I did a fresh install of Python 3.8.2 on a Win7 VM, but when I want to run any python script in cmd.exe, e.g.,

```
test.py
```

a window pops up, asking about the program to use to open test.py.

The properties for that file state that it opens with "General Windows shell DLL".

I know I can set this association manually, but why isn't it set automatically, as the Python Windows FAQ states it should?  I'm preparing some installation instructions for a Python tool of mine, but it's no good if the installer behaves randomly.

Comment: OK, I've learned that for some unknown reason, the file association only works for the UI, but not cmd.exe.  So is there no way to replicate the sane behavior of other platforms as far as the command line is concerned?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a python script with a cmd or powershell, you have to type `python test.py` (or `py test.py` if that's available).

Setting file association makes it possible to launch a specific program when opening a file with a extension that's been associated with it, but it really only makes sense for the graphical user interface (i.e windows exlorer). If you want to emulate this behavior in cmd, type `start some_file`, but this should only be used for very specific reasons as it is dependant on the machine.

Comment: You're right, https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#from-file-associations only talks about double-clicking on a .py file.  This is really hare-brained, though.